# How to define name of a range with duplicate values in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I'd like to know how to define name for a range with duplicate values and have it automatically run through a the whole table. Please see the table below.

```
    A       B
1   CODE    Display
2   100     000
3   100     000
4   100     010
5   100     020
6   100     030
7   100     100
8   110     000
9   110     010
10  110     020
11  110     030
12  110     100
13  110     101
14  110     200
15  110     204
16  110     208
17  110     209
```

Now, I know that I can use the method Names.Add to define. However, my problem is to be able to get the name range of the duplicate values in **Column A** as shown in the snippet.

I want to define name of **Range B2:B7** as "t_100", for example. What I can think of is to get the address range from A2:A7, offset 1 column, then use the Names.Add method to refers to B2:B7. And since A2:A7 range contains only "100", it begs the question how to get the range of a continues duplicate values.

That's my initial thought.

Comment: If `A` column is ordered, you may use a loop and `union` to determine the range. Immediately after the value of `A` column has changed teh union range can be given name. then loop back and start a new union. Try some code.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering on a known value and then referencing the `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible` would be a good method of gathering the cells with duplicate column A values together. Counting to see if any particular value was the first occurrence of that value as you walked down the column would ensure that you were not unnecessarily repeating actions.

```
Sub t_000_name_table()
    Dim rw As Long, val As Variant
    With ActiveSheet
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter
            For rw = 2 To .Rows.Count
                val = .Cells(rw, 1).Value
                If Not CBool(Application.CountIf(.Cells(1, 1).Resize(rw - 1, 1), val)) Then
                    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=val
                    With .Offset(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
                        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Name = Format(val, "\t\_000")
                    End With
                    .AutoFilter field:=1
                End If
            Next rw
            .AutoFilter
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I've used a shorthand name declaration statement which replies heavily on the defaults. It should come in as *workbook scope* and *absolute cell range addressing* for the *Refers to:*. If you wish to alter the scope or other property, you can use the MSDN VBA reference for [Name Object .Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221688%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

This should work well for non-contiguous ranges as well.